# Pushing my application.config file to my spark job worker nodes

Tags: scala, apache-spark

My spark job is failing and it looks like the reason is that my configuration file is not found on the worker node.

My config file is currently in:

```
/src/main/resources/application.conf
```

I copied the file to the root folder where I run the spark-submit command and I did this:

```
spark-submit --class "com.path.to.main.MainClass" --master local[*] --files application.conf /path/to/jar.jar
```

That didn't seem to work either as I got the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `--master local[*]` tells it you're using the local machine, not any kind of cluster.

Comment: Could you add the error?